# Double counting in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table of `Employees`, and related table of the `Group of Employees`
The relationship is one to many, when the - `id` from the table `Employee groups` can appear many times in the table - `Employees`
I want to know which employee group contains the most Employees.
Or, in other words, some of `emp_group ID` appears most frequently `Employees` table.
How can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic aggregation query:

```
select top (1) with ties groupid, count(*) as numemployees
from employee_groups
group by groupid
order by count(*);
```

Answer (score 0):

A 'top 1 with ties' is one way to do it.

But a DENSE_RANK can also be used for this.
A descending DENSE_RANK on the count would give the top groups the same number 1.

```sql
select groupid, total_employees
from (
  select 
   groupid, 
   count(distinct employeeid) as total_employees,
   dense_rank() over (order by count(distinct employeeid) desc) as rn
  from [Group of Employees]
  group by groupid
) q
where rn = 1
order by groupid;
```